# How to suppress gfortran compiler flag

Tags: fortran, mingw, gfortran

I'm new to fortran and I'm trying to compile a program with the gfortran MinGW compiler but I keep getting the following error message:

Error: Line truncated at (1) [-Werror=line-truncation]

f951.exe: some warnings being treated as errors

The easy way would be to just make sure the line doesn't pass the boundary, but this program isn't mine, I'm just working on a script that uses it. So I would prefer a method where I don't need to fix the syntax. I know there's a way to suppress the line-truncation compiler flag I just have no idea where I would disable that. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: What options are you using when compiling?

Comment: The linked answers say how to disable the lenght limit. That is what you actually want to do. Just disabling the warning does not help, you would get a different error because the commands would be cropped.